# how to correctly structure reducer when trying to do filter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, redux, lodash

Looking at https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter

I have an array of objects, and each object looks something like this:

```
{
  id: 10005,
  title: 'Brooklyn Bridge by Night',
  author: 'Charles Gooding',
  takenOn: 'some date',
  description: 'Photo of the Brooklyn Bridge at night.  Taken from somewhere I am just making this up to be honest.',
  cameraId: 301,
  // some other stuff
}
```

I am trying to do a quick filter and here's my reducer for `FILTER_RESULTS`.  How can I avoid having to use an array that is built up?

```
case 'FILTER_RESULTS':
  const results = [];
  state.photos.map((a) => {
    Object.keys(a).forEach((b) => {
      if (a[b].toLowerCase().includes(action.value.toLowerCase())) {
        results.push(a); // also a question on this one
      }
    });
    return results;
  });
  return {
    ...state,
    state.photosFilter: results
  }
```

Also, how can I make sure that the object I push into results is unique?  Thanks

Comment: Your first code was ignoring the return value of `.map()`. Now you have two return values in a row, and no closing brackets. At some point you'll need to post some code that actually represents whatever you're doing.

Comment: There's also a bunch of unknowns here, including what the final result is supposed to be.

Comment: @squint sorry for the confusion I've updated

Comment: The final result is the array of objects which contains some text to filter by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make small, narrow functions; they are easy to understand and combine.

```
function includesAttributes(thing, target) {
   return _.some(Object.keys(thing), 
                 (key) => thing[key].toLowerCase().includes(target.toLowerCase()));
}
```

Then

```
case 'FILTER_RESULTS':
  return state.photos.filter((record) => includesAttribute(record, action.value));
```

Comment: Thanks.  That is amazing!